# Login with only email in Lumen (JWT Auth)

Tags: laravel, authentication, jwt, lumen

I want to make the password optional while login into the system. If the user enters the password the login works fine and return the jwt token, when I entered to try to login only with email it gives the following error:-

```
Undefined index: password (500 Internal Server Error)
```

The following is the code of my login method

```
public function authenticateUser($request)
    {
        $input = $request->only('email','password');
        if (!$authorized = Auth::attempt($input, true)) {
            return $this->failure('Credentials doesnot match our records!', 401);
        } else {
            $token = $this->respondWithToken($authorized);
            return $this->success('Login Successfully !', $token, 200);
        }
    }

protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        return [
            'token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'Bearer',
            'expires_in' => Auth::factory()->getTTL() * 60,
            'user' =>  Auth::user()
        ];
    }
```

so basically, what I want is when a user enters an email it will login and should return the token, and if the user login with email and password then it should also work and return the token.

Comment: what are you using for JWT auth?

Comment: I am using jwt authentication package that I installed in lumen, and sending the email and password to login, but I want make password optional , when I registered if user want to register only with email he will enter only email and password will be null

Comment: yes what package are you using?

Comment: https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/lumen-installation/

Comment: @lagbox can you help me on this ?

Comment: yea I will write something up to try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227382/discussion-between-arslan-akram-and-lagbox).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom Authentication User Provider that will work around this potentially missing 'password' field. Though, I would probably not here. You can check the input yourself to see if there is a password or not. If there is pass it through `attempt` like normal. If it is not there find the user using the configured User Provider and login to the guard (what `attempt` is doing).

Perhaps something like this:

```
public function authenticateUser($request)
{
    if ($request->has('password')) {
        $token = Auth::attempt($request->only(['email', 'password']));
    } else {
        $token = ($user = Auth::getProvider()->retrieveByCredentials($request->only(['email'])))
            ? Auth::login($user)
            : false;
    }

    return $token
        ? $this->success('Login Successfully !', $this->respondWithToken($token), 200)
        : $this->failure('Credentials do not match our records!', 401);
}
```

Comment: You are my hero, the retrieveByCredentials did the trick

Answer (score 0):

The error that you're getting means that there is no `password` key in the input array that you're sending via request. This happens on this line:

```
$input = $request->only('email','password');
```

In order to bypass that, you would need go get all inputs, or check if those inputs exist and then read from them:

```
//Get all inputs    
$input = $request->input();
//Or get email first, and then check for password
$input['email'] = $request->email;
$input['password'] = $request->filled('password') ? $request->password : null;
```

Note: Since I can't see your actual login functions, this might not work with only email, since password might be required parameter. If that's the case, you will have to alter those functions.

Comment: which login function  you want to see ? when I entered without password it asking "credentials does not match our records"

Comment: `only` will just not set the key in the result if it doesn't exist, it doesn't cause an error

Comment: @ArslanAkram the `Auth::attempt($input, true)` one. I'm not sure if that's your function or external package, but that might require password to always be present.

Comment: @lagbox I didn't know that, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @zlatan ``` Auth::attempt($input , true) ``` is builtin function , that's not my function

Comment: @zlatan you are correct, that method most likely is expecting there to be a password key

Comment: @lagbox so what should i do ?